# Trying to find timestamp out of order. By testing for NOT in a back reference in Notepad

Tags: regex, notepad++

Example logs

```
2024-01-19 13:09:22.616 Message="one"
2024-01-19 13:09:22.721 Message="two"
2024-01-19 14:09:22.814 Message="three"
2024-01-19 13:09:22.902 Message="four"
```

Message `three` is out of order and the one to find. (should be within same minutes)

I can find it using notepad++ in regex mode and search for:

```
\d\d 13:(\d\d):.*[\r\n]+.*14:\1
```

So I like to expand my search and put hour in first group and search for hour not on next line.
This is some I have tried but not working:

```
\d\d (\d\d):(\d\d):.*[\r\n]+.*(?:(?!\1)):\2
```

Here I add the hour to group #1 and minitues to group #2 then test for not group #1 and then match group #2 the minutes.

Comment: Like this? `\b\d\d (\d\d):(\d\d):.*\R\d{4}-\d\d-\d\d (?!\1)\d+:\2` https://regex101.com/r/nzP4Ng/1 So you capture the hour and the minutes and then on the next like you match the hours if not the same as in group 1, and then the minutes have to be the same.

Comment: @Thefourthbird Perfect.  Post it as an answer and I give you points for it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use the negative lookahead for the assertions, but you are not actually matching the digits.

This part `(?:(?!\1))` can be written as `(?!\1)` without the non capture group.

To get the match using `.*` and relying on the presence of the digit part with the colon and a leading space (as all lines have the same format):

```
\d\d (\d\d):(\d\d):.*\R.* (?!\1)\d+:\2
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/wJJLfX/1)

Or if you want to match only that third line, you can use `\K` and then match the rest of the line:

```
\d\d (\d\d):(\d\d):.*\R\K.* (?!\1)\d+:\2\b.*
```

---

A more precise match, but maybe overkill:

```
^\d{4}-\d\d-\d\d\h(\d\d):(\d\d):.*\R\d{4}-\d\d-\d\d\h(?!\1)\d+:\2:
```

Comment: Came up with almost similar regex but you are super fast

Comment: @anubhava I learned from the best :-)

Comment: May be (just may be) we can add `\K` after `\R` to match only desired line

Comment: Thanks to both of you for an ultrafast answer.  No I can search trough around 300K of log lines and try to see what are the modules to are using wrong time :)